# Inkscape's mesh tool gradient in the fill not allowing to change colors

Tags: inkscape, gradient-mesh

I am new to Inkscape, thank you for your patience.
When I try to create a gradient in the fill, the mesh tool does not show the mesh points needed to change color. However, the tool allows me to change color at each mesh point when I create a gradient in the stroke. How can I get Inkscape to show the mesh points when I try to create a gradient in the fill so that I can change the colors?

I attached an image of the mesh points that I want to see when I try to create a mesh gradient in the fill but Inkscape does not show them.

Thank you[image: These are the mesh points that I want to see when I try to create a mesh gradient in the fill but Inkscape does not show them]

Comment: I'm afraid your patiency has hard times with Inkscape's meshes. They are not colors, but objects which are constructed to be masked by either the stroke or the interior of a shape. One must set in the beginning in the options bar if the mesh is used for a stroke or shape interior.  I have never succeeded to make them obey my will. I guess they are still under programming effort. In the options bar there's even a warning of forthcoming radical changes. But no reason to complain, in Inkscape there's still plenty of useful stuff for $0,-

Answer (score 1):

Select the Gradient Mesh tool [image] in the toolbox.

In the tool options along the top select the *Create Gradient Mesh* and the *Create Gradient in the Fill* buttons.

[image]

Apply a gradient mesh by using the Gradient Mesh tool, and by clicking and dragging on a selected shape.

Like this

[image]

That should show the mesh.

Next you need to select the Mesh gradient stops to change the colour.

There are two tools you can use for this, either the Gradient Mesh tool itself, or the Pick Colours tool (aka the Eyedropper).

The stops are coloured grey, so you can see them

Example

[image]

**A word of warning**: Gradient Meshes are not currently supported in web browsers. So if this is for SVG output for the web, you'd  need to rasterize it if you want to use it in an SVG. You can use *Edit > Make a bitmap copy* to do that.

That said, there are lots of nice things you can do with meshes. The interface is a little fiddly/tricky, but with patience the results can be worth the effort.

[image]